# Unique set sums from a list

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, set, unique

I'm doing some algorithm practice and came across this.

I have a list/array, something like this: [1, 5, 4, 9, 10, 2, ...]

How would I go about returning finding unique sets of the list that have the same sum? For example, (5, 4) would equal (9) and (1, 5) would equal 6 and so on.

I am familiar with finding all the sets of a list, but the added trick to this is that the sets have to be unique as in if one index was used for one set, the same index cannot be used for the other set.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Edit:

After thinking about this some more, here is what I have. I make a list of all possible sets, not worrying about unique. Then I get the min and max of the original superset array. I loop through the values from min to max, incrementing by 1 and check each set. Create a hashmap. If the sum of the set is equal to the value we are checking, we add that set to a list. Additionally, we set the value associated key in the hashmap to True if the the value of an index of a set has a key. Keep on checking each set with the hashmap conditional. Then we return the list of list that should only have the unique sets.

Make sense?

Comment: I think you don't mean unique, but [disjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets). And I hope `1+5 = 6`, not 5.

Comment: I think this is not properly defined - you want to return any collection of disjoint sets? or the maximal/minimal one? In any case your solution is exponential in time and space, so im pretty sure its possible to do better..

Comment: Any collection of disjoint sets. Yeah, first crack is exponential, trying to get it down.

Edit: Rather, it's O(n) for a single sum plus the recursive calls. It becomes exponential if I loop through for the whole range.

Comment: `I make a list of all possible sets` - this alone is exponential by  definition in time and memory.

Answer (score 2):

`make a list of all possible sets` - this is of course exponential in time and space. Here is a polynomial time solution (If I understood the problem):

1. iterate over the list, keeping two pointers -  For every time the first one is incremented the second one runs from that index+1 to the end of the list.
2. For every combination of two elements, if their sum is lower than the required sum, their combined value is pushed into the end of the list(keeping the original indexes that comprised it).
3. once a combination of elements that equals exactly the sum is found, all the elements in the corresponding indexes are rmoved from the list, and that set is inserted into the solution vector of disjointed sets.

At the end of this iterative process you will have a complete set of disjointed sets - not necessarily the one with the most number of elements or the most number of groups, but one that no other set could be created from the remaining elements in the list.

Comment: Does #2 remove the original indices? If not, how do you prevent it from just combining in the same element multiple times? e.g. if you have 1,2,4,5, you combine 1+2 -> 1,2,4,5,3, (eventually) combine 2+3 (2 repeated). I think you need to explain with an example.

Comment: @Dukeling #2 does not remove the original indices, but pushes into the array a struct containing a value and a list of its originating indexes, both to use when constructing back the final set, and to ensure that a number is repeated as in your example. if a combination containing a atruct equals exactly the sum, all the elements comprising the struct are also removed. Thats the idea.. Ill write up an example later when I have the time.